# ListView: change siblings' data dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-view, android-adapterview

I have a `ListView` with items containing each one a `SeekBar`.

What I want to achieve is that when one of the `SeekBar`s is slowly slided, the rest of the `SeekBar`s gracefully slide at the same time (this is, I want the events of one items to make effect on the rest of the list items).

I tried to store all the views in an array of views inside the adapter, but I was getting unexpected and unpredictable behavior (I guess it is related to the way ListView manages the child items internally).

Any hint on how this should be properly done?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve the problem using RxJava.

Basically, you have a stream of data (`Seekbar`'s current position) and have arbitrary amount of subscribers (each `Seekbar` of each row).

You need some kind of `Observable`, that possesses following features:

1. you can set a value to that `Observable`
2. upon subscription you are able to receive the value, that was previously dispatched

Turns out [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) is the one that you need.

So, having declared a `BehaviorSubject` this was:

```
BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0); // default value is 0
```

Now anytime any `Seekbar`'s value is changed just perform `subject.onNext(currentPosition)`.

As soon as the view is being shown on the screen - subscribe to the stream:

```
Disposable d = subject.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        seekbar.setProgress(integer);
    }
)
```

When the view is being recycled - dispose from the `Disposable`:

```
d.dispose();
```

Comment: Man, that was pure magic. Thank you very much! The bits I didnt get is "as soon as the view is being shown", how do I know this? I can't see any hook... The same for "when the view is being recycled". How do I know this? For my first shot, I subscribe to the subject in the very "getView()" method of the Adapter, and I don't dispose yet.

Comment: I do not remember the API of `ListView`, but for `RecyclerView` those callbacks would be `onBindViewHolder()` and `onViewRecycled()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with fancy stuff like RxJava or [event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), or without external dependencies:

```
class MyObjAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyObjAdapter.MyObjViewHolder> {

    class MyObjViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        SeekBar bar;

        MyObjViewHolder(View itemView, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            bar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bar);
            bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(listener);
        }

    }

    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private int value = 0;
    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener listener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                value = progress;
                int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                notifyItemRangeChanged(firstVisiblePosition,
                        layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() - firstVisiblePosition + 1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    };


    public MyObjAdapter(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public MyObjViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        return new MyObjViewHolder(view, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyObjViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bar.setProgress(value);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```